# Duplicates in Access report- multivalued fields

Tags: ms-access, duplicates, report

Pretty sure my issue is due to multivalued combo box fields-

I don't get duplicates in my query, but I do get duplicates in the report based on that query. It appears the duplicates are for records that have more than one value selected in one or more multivalued fields.

I've checked and the query is not using .Value fields. As far as I can tell the query is fine- it's the report that's creating duplicates.

Table design:
[Table design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wuT16.jpg)

Multivalued fields are lookup fields that lookup values from a table:
Resource Categories
Provider type
Type/Format of Resource or Service
Target users
Accessibility

These fields are lookups with single choice combo box:
Local or National

Comment: Can you show us any sample data or queries? We need a starting point so we can better help you. Please read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Query SQL:SELECT [RESOURCES DATABASE].ID, [RESOURCES DATABASE].[Resource Categories], [RESOURCES DATABASE].[Resource or Service Title], [RESOURCES DATABASE].Provider, [RESOURCES DATABASE].URL, [RESOURCES DATABASE].[Provider type], [RESOURCES DATABASE].[Type/Format of Resource or Service], [RESOURCES DATABASE].[Date of publication], [RESOURCES DATABASE].[Resource or Service Description], [RESOURCES DATABASE].[Target users], [RESOURCES DATABASE].[Local or National], [RESOURCES DATABASE].Region, [RESOURCES DATABASE].Accessibility
FROM [RESOURCES DATABASE];

Comment: @AlyxPerry That's a start, but you did not specify which column, if any, is the multi-valued field.  Also, it is best to edit and improve the main question text.  You can also add code formatting to help set it apart and make it more readable.

Comment: What grouping and sorting is on the report?  I assume ID is a primary key, correct? Temporarily add a Total Count to the report.  Does the count reflect the duplicate values, or is only printing records more than once?